# Excel: Find matching hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hyperlink

After spending some time searching the 'net for an answer without success here's my question:

I have two workbooks, let's call them 'profiles' and 'results'.

In 'profiles' I have a sheet which has hyperlinks in A3 to A2000. Names appear in these cells, such as 'Jim', 'Dave', 'Anne' etc. The underlying hyperlinks differ only by a particular name's ID, such as 'www.destinationwebsite.com/nameID'. nameID being different in every case.

In 'results' I have a sheet and a single instance of any of these names/hyperlinks could appear anywhere in C3 to Cx.

At the moment I'm just doing a basic comparison between the names in the two workbooks, and this works informing me if the name in 'profiles' is in 'results'. However should there be two or more 'Jim's in 'results' (with different IDs) then it doesn't work. The only way round this is to actually be checking for matching hyperlinks ('nameID') to be sure I'm referencing the correct 'Jim'.

After spending some time on this I've had to admit defeat - surely doing something so basic should be easy to do in Excel.

Any help would be appreciated in getting past this stumbling block.

Comment: The results sheet has the same format - a name with a hyperlink attached? And you want to.. check for missing ones? Remove duplicates? And how were the hyperlinks created? You're not going to be able to do this with simple formula, I don't think.

Comment: Yes, same format. The profile worksheet contains the names of almost 2000 people in cells A3 to A2000. Each of these cells is a hyperlink, each URL being different due to the 'nameID'. These cells never change, new ones may get inserted if a new person needs adding. What I'm looking to do is put a formula in cell B3 that checks the results worksheet in another workbook for matches to the hyperlink in A3. If there's a match it returns true, false if it's not.

Comment: This will need VBA - working with hyperlink addresses is difficult enough with VBA, I don't even know if it's possible to do with a formula other than creating a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sub CheckLinks()
Dim WBprofiles As Workbook
Set WBprofiles = ThisWorkbook
Dim WBresults As Workbook
Set WBresults = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\path\to\results.xlsx")

Dim WSprofiles As Worksheet
Set WSprofiles = WBprofiles.Sheets("profiles")
Dim WSresults As Worksheet
Set WSresults = WBresults.Sheets("results")

Dim DictResults As Object
Set DictResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = WSresults.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim strKey As String
For d = 1 To lastrow
    strKey = Cells(d, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
    DictResults(strKey) = 1
Next

Dim vResult() As Variant
ReDim vResult(DictResults.Count - 1, 1)
Dim x As Integer

For Each Key In DictResults.keys
    vResult(x, 0) = Key
    x = x + 1
Next

lastrow = WSprofiles.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim strLoc As String
Dim i As Integer
For Each link In WSprofiles.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Hyperlinks
    strLoc = link.Address
    For i = LBound(vResult) To UBound(vResult)
        If vResult(i, 0) = strLoc Then
            link.Range.Offset(, 1) = "Found"
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian for taking the time to do this, I'll give it a try tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: This uses a dictionary to avoid duplicates, if there's no duplicates, there's no need for the dictionary. I don't know why I thought there were duplicates.